# VirtualBox failed install on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I'm attempting to install VirtualBox via the Ubunutu Software Center and keep getting the following error message:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
virtualbox-qt: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
Depends: libqt4-opengl (>= 4:4.7.2) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
Depends: virtualbox (= 4.3.10-dfsg-1) but 4.3.10-dfsg-1 is to be installed
```

I find this odd, note that it appears to say that all the packages that are needed meet the version requirements, but then they are rejected?  I've tried installing all the packages above manually, and I get a message saying:

```
the package 'is already the newest version'
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading it from the Official Virtual Box Website.

From your favorite terminal and text editor

Add the following line at the end of your /etc/apt/sources.list

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Go to the end of the file and add

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
```

Save and exit, and run

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.3 dkms
```

And then, install the extension pack

```
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.20/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.20-96996.vbox-extpack 

sudo VBoxManage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.20-96996.vbox-extpack
```